# Unaggregated gradients / gradients per example in tensorflow

Tags: tensorflow

Given a simple mini-batch gradient descent problem on mnist in tensorflow (like in this [tutorial](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/master/tensorflow/examples/tutorials/mnist/mnist_with_summaries.py)), how can I retrieve the gradients for each example in the batch individually.

`tf.gradients()` seems to return gradients averaged over all examples in the batch. Is there a way to retrieve gradients before aggregation?

Edit: A first step towards this answer is figuring out at which point tensorflow averages the gradients over the examples in the batch. I thought this happened in [_AggregatedGrads](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/8048088bfb82846078f8023bc6199e6424926624/tensorflow/python/ops/gradients.py#L437), but that doesn't appear to be the case. Any ideas?

Comment: It sounds like you want a jacobian, not a gradient.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`tf.gradients` returns the gradient with respect to the loss. This means that if your loss is a sum of per-example losses, then the gradient is also the sum of per-example loss gradients.

The summing up is implicit. For instance if you want to minimize the sum of squared norms of `Wx-y` errors, the gradient with respect to `W` is `2(WX-Y)X'` where `X` is the batch of observations and `Y` is the batch of labels. You never explicitly form "per-example" gradients that you later sum up, so it's not a simple matter of removing some stage in the gradient pipeline.

A simple way to get `k` per-example loss gradients is to use batches of size 1 and do `k` passes. Ian Goodfellow [wrote up](http://arxiv.org/pdf/1510.01799v2.pdf) how to get all `k` gradients in a single pass, for this you would need to specify gradients explicitly and not rely on `tf.gradients` method

Comment: You can use tf.gradients to do most of the work. Say you want per-example gradients with respect to X. You call tf.gradients on the consumers of X. Say for example you have a variable Z that is X multiplied by some matrix W. Then you need your own logic to do per-example differentiation through matrix multiplication, but you can use tf.gradients to get the derivatives with respect to Z.

Comment: Thanks! Just to make sure I understand this correctly: this would only work up to the first matrix multiplication in the back propagation chain, right? Meaning that computing the derivatives for the weights of the first layer in an MLP would require implementing almost all the steps of back prop. anyway?

Comment: If the loss is a sum of per-example losses then there is no issue whatsoever tf.gradients is computing the right thing which is the sum of per-example loss gradients. The thing is that when the "loss" is a function that returns a scalar for each example.

Answer (score 1):

To partly answer my own question after tinkering with this for a while. It appears that it is possible to manipulate gradients per example while still working in batch by doing the following:

- Create a copy of tf.gradients() that accepts an extra tensor/placeholder with example-specific factors
- Create a copy of _AggregatedGrads() and add a custom aggregation method that uses the example-specific factors
- Call your custom tf.gradients function and give your loss as a list of slices:

`custagg_gradients(
          ys=[cross_entropy[i] for i in xrange(batch_size)],

          xs=variables.trainable_variables(), 
          aggregation_method=CUSTOM, 
          gradient_factors=gradient_factors
    )`

But this will probably have the same complexity as doing individual passes per example, and I need to check if the gradients are correct :-).

Answer (score 1):

One way of retrieving gradients before aggregation is to use the `grads_ys` parameter. A good discussion is found here:

[Use of grads_ys parameter in tf.gradients - TensorFlow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42399401/use-of-grads-ys-parameter-in-tf-gradients-tensorflow)

EDIT:

I haven't been working with Tensorflow a lot lately, but here is an open issue tracking the best way to compute unaggregated gradients:

https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/675

There is a lot of sample code solutions provided by users (including myself) that you can try based on your needs.

Comment: Can you elaborate on this? Maybe provide a code example of how you can get the individual example gradients with this approach?