# Separate gradients in tf.gradients

Tags: tensorflow

Based on this [reference](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/train/gradient_computation#gradients), `tf.gradients` returns the partial derivatives of **sum** of `ys` w.r.t. `x` in `xs`.

Is it possible to get separate values for each `x` in `xs`?

**Example**. Please look at the following code:

```
import tensorflow as tf
import numpy as np

x = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, shape=[None, 2])
w = tf.Variable(dtype=tf.float32, initial_value=[[4],[5]])
z = tf.matmul(x, w)
g = tf.gradients(z, w)

s = tf.InteractiveSession()
s.run(tf.global_variables_initializer())

x_ = np.matrix('1,0;0,1;0,0;2,1')
s.run(g, feed_dict={x: x_})
```

It simply calculates `dz/dw` which is `x`. But `g` returns the sum of `x`:

```
[array([[ 3.],
    [ 2.]], dtype=float32)]
```

What I need is a separate value for each row in `x`.

Comment: No straightforward way, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35731506/unaggregated-gradients-gradients-per-example-in-tensorflow , https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/4897 for background why