# Use of grads_ys parameter in tf.gradients - TensorFlow

Tags: tensorflow

I want to understand the `grad_ys` paramter in `tf.gradients`. I've seen it used like a multiplyer of the true gradient but its not crear in the definition. Mathematically how would the whole expression look like?

Answer (score 12):

Edit: better clarification of notation is [here](https://medium.com/@yaroslavvb/backprop-and-systolic-arrays-24e925d2050)

`ys` are summed up to make a single scalar `y`, and then `tf.gradients` computes `dy/dx` where `x` represents variables from `xs`

`grad_ys` represent the "starting" backprop value. They are 1 by default, but a different value can be when you want to chain several `tf.gradients` calls together -- you can pass in the output of previous `tf.gradients` call into `grad_ys` to continue the backprop flow.

For formal definition, look at the chained expression in Reverse Accumulation here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Automatic_differentiation#Reverse_accumulation

The term corresponding to `dy/dw3 * dw3/dw2` in TensorFlow is a vector of 1's (think of it as if TensorFlow wraps cost with a dummy identity op). When you specify `grad_ys` this term is replaced with `grad_ys` instead of vector of `1`s

[image]

Comment: Can you give me the "formal" definition. Is it `tf.gradients(y, x, grad_ys) = grad_ys * diff(y, x)` ???

Comment: Or maybe can you give an example?

Comment: added a formal definition

Comment: I'm still not understanding it.
Can you put the whole formal definition in your answer?
Particularly since wikipedia is likely to change over time.

Comment: I've added a "formal picture". "grad" is the same as the "grad" argument that's fed into function that you register using `@ops.RegisterGradient`

Comment: @YaroslavBulatov if your Y vector was equivalent to your loss w/ respect to each input in a minibatch. Would grad_ys be equivalent to weights for each each gradient per record in the minibatch? My initial thoughts are no from a test example I coded up.

Comment: grad_ys is the vector of "backprops", I wrote up a complete example [here](https://medium.com/@yaroslavvb/backprop-and-systolic-arrays-24e925d2050). In that example, default grad_ys is the first vector of backprops (transpose of activations), but you can substitute a different version using `grad_ys` param

Comment: @YaroslavBulatov Could you clarify - when the loss is scalar (e.g. MSE), ``y`` is a scalar, so ``grad_ys`` should also be a scalar. How can I feed it with the gradients for the model weights? (as you specified, "you can pass in the output of previous tf.gradients call") when I simply feed it the previous gradients it has mismatched size. Thanks!

Comment: @CristianGarcia I also think the formal definition corresponds to your math equation?  right?

Comment: @yoki grad_ys has dimension of input to loss op, not the output of that op. IE, MSE takes vector of activations, and produces scalar loss. grad_ys has dimensionality of that vector