# Using TensorFlow ``grad_loss / grad_ys`` parameter to add gradients

Tags: python, tensorflow

I'm trying to use the `grad_loss` parameter in `optimizer.minimize(loss, grad_loss=)` to modify the network gradients with existing gradients.
I followed the comments here:
[Use of grads_ys parameter in tf.gradients - TensorFlow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42399401/use-of-grads-ys-parameter-in-tf-gradients-tensorflow)

and I would like to run a toy example, in which I recreate the default `1` values for `grad_ys`, as specified in the documentation.

Here's the relevant code segment:

```
grads_and_vars = optimizer.compute_gradients(loss_op) 
vars_with_grad = [v for g, v in grads_and_vars if g is not None] 
grad_loss = [] 
for grad,var in grads_and_vars:
    grad_loss.append(tf.ones_like(grad))
train_op = optimizer.minimize(loss_op, grad_loss=grad_loss)
```

The first part extracts gradients using `compute_gradients`. The last line computes gradients of the loss function `loss_op` but attempts to use `1`-filled vectors for the grads. As far as I understand, this should behave similarly to funning `minimize` without the `grad_loss` parameter.

Unfortunately, this fails since it expects `grad_loss` to be a Tensor (and have a dtype) and not a list. Looking into `gradients_impl.py` I see that the function expected `grad_loss` to be of the same dimension as `loss` (which in this case is a scalar).

I would appreciate any assistance in this simple example - how do I add elements to the gradients this way?

EDIT: I guess the question boils down to the definition of `grad_loss`: "A `Tensor` holding the gradient computed for `loss`." How do I generate such a tensor from a set of gradients obtained by `compute_gradients`?

Thanks.

Comment: So what is your purpose? According to my understanding, if loss is not a scalar then you have to pass `grad_loss` to the function and `grad_loss` is the gradient of your object w.rt loss.

Comment: My loss is scalar, but the gradients are vectors, matrices, etc. (according to the model and weights I train). What I do not understand is how to provide the function with my modified gradients.

Comment: see https://github.com/tensorflow/models/blob/master/tutorials/image/cifar10/cifar10_multi_gpu_train.py to understand how to provide custom gradients for optimizer

Comment: In this example they use "opt.apply_gradients" for a custom gradient. However, I would like to use the same original gradients but modify them in the exact manner as ``grad_loss`` aims to provide. I believe there is a technical detail I am missing.

Answer (score 0):

You can make use of the `tf.convert_to_tensor` method to convert your list of gradients to a `tensor`, and then use `tf.reduce_sum`:

```
train_op = optimizer.minimize(loss_op, grad_loss=tf.reduce_sum(tf.convert_to_tensor(grad_loss)))
```