# Can I get unaggregated gradient from tensorflow?

Tags: tensorflow, reinforcement-learning, gradient

I'm trying to implement reinforcement learning using tensorflow, follow this paper: http://www.kyb.mpg.de/fileadmin/user_upload/files/publications/attachments/Neural-Netw-2008-21-682_4867%5b0%5d.pdf

On page 687, table 4, they have a formula to calculate the optimal baseline. But that require to get unaggregated gradients first, do some calculation then mean over the batch.

But `tf.gradients` returns us already aggregated gradients. Is there a way to do that? There are also similar question: [Unaggregated gradients / gradients per example in tensorflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35731506/unaggregated-gradients-gradients-per-example-in-tensorflow) , of course, we can do runtime `tf.while_loop` over batch size, and get single gradient one by one, but that will kill the performance.